# Does python3 lose performance over python2 in strength length calculation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, performance

I've noticed performance degradation in string length calculation when profiling my ported code from python2 to python3. See a test example below.

Is there any way I can make the python3 implementation match the performance of python2?

Note that nsec = 1000 * usec

```
python2 -m timeit -n 10000000 "len('foo')"
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0294 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit -n 10000000 "len('foo')"
> 10000000 loops, best of 5: 44.1 nsec per loop (0.0441 usec)
```

Comment: The difference is almost negligible, and both are guaranteed constant time. Why do you care? Anyway, without some serious hacking, there is nothing you can do about the implementation of `list.__len__` which is probably just a simple attribute access anyway.

Comment: An interface got slower, why would you not care?

Comment: Because it is *negligible*. It won't affect the overall performance of my code at all. Why *would* I care?

Comment: In any event, it's probably due to changes in the `len` function, not `list.__len__`, although I'm only guessing. Likely, `len` does more/different sanity checks in Python 3.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry, `str.__len__`, and actually, this *may in fact* be due to differences in `str.__len__`, since `str` in Python2 is equivalent to `bytes` in Python 3. Try using a unicode literal in your Python 2 code, so `"len(u'foo')"`